# Vuejs Laravel Passport - what should I do if access token is expired?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, token, vuex, laravel-passport

I am using Vuejs SPA with Laravel API as backend. I successfully got the personal access token and store in localStorage and Vuex state like below.

```
token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
expiresAt: localStorage.getItem('expiresAt') || '',
```

I use the access token every time I send axios request to laravel api. Every thing works well. However, initially the token was set to 1 year expiration so when I develop I didn't care about token being expired and today suddenly I thought what is going to happen if token expired. So I set token expiry to 10 seconds in laravel AuthServiceProvier.php.

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addSecond(10));
```

and then I logged in and after 10 seconds, every requests stopped working because the token was expired and got 401 unauthorised error.

In this case, how can I know if the token is expired? I would like to redirect the user to login page if token is expired when the user is using the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I do. Axios will throw error if the response code is 4xx or 5xx, and then I add an if to check if response status is 401, then redirect to login page.

```
export default {
    methods: {
        loadData () {
            axios
                .request({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: 'https://mysite/api/route',
                })
                .then(response => {
                    // assign response.data to a variable
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    if (error.response.status === 401) {
                        this.$router.replace({name: 'login'})
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}
```

But if you do it like this, you have to copy paste the catch on all axios call inside your programs. 
The way I did it is to put the code above to a javascript files api.js, import the class to main.js, and assign it to Vue.prototype.$api

```
import api from './api'
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$api', { value: api })
```

So that in my component, I just call the axios like this.

```
this.$api.GET(url, params)
    .then(response => {
        // do something
    })
```

The error is handled on api.js.
This is my full api.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import router from '@/router'

let config = {
  baseURL : process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_API,
  timeout : 30000,
  headers : {
    Accept         : 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
  },
}

const GET = (url, params) => REQUEST({ method: 'get', url, params })
const POST = (url, data) => REQUEST({ method: 'post', url, data })
const PUT = (url, data) => REQUEST({ method: 'put', url, data })
const PATCH = (url, data) => REQUEST({ method: 'patch', url, data })
const DELETE = url => REQUEST({ method: 'delete', url })

const REQUEST = conf => {
  conf = { ...conf, ...config }
  conf = setAccessTokenHeader(conf)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios
      .request(conf)
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        outputError(error)
        reject(error)
      })
  })
}

function setAccessTokenHeader (config) {
  const access_token = Vue.cookie.get('access_token')
  if (access_token) {
    config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token
  }

  return config
}

/* https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors */
function outputError (error) {
  if (error.response) {
    /**
     * The request was made and the server responded with a
     * status code that falls out of the range of 2xx
     */
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      router.replace({ name: 'login' })
      return
    }
    else {
      /* other response status such as 403, 404, 422, etc */
    }
  }
  else if (error.request) {
    /**
     * The request was made but no response was received
     * `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser
     * and an instance of http.ClientRequest in node.js
     */
  }
  else {
    /* Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error */
  }
}

export default {
  GET,
  POST,
  DELETE,
  PUT,
  PATCH,
  REQUEST,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Be as user friendly as possible. Rather than waiting until the token expires, receiving a 401 error response, and then redirecting, set up a token verification check on the mounted hook of your main SPA instance and have it make a ajax call to e.g. `/validatePersonalToken` on the server, then do something like this in your routes or controller.

```
Route::get('/validatePersonalToken', function () {
      return ['message' => 'is valid'];
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

This should return `"error": "Unauthenticated"` if the token is not valid.  This way the user will be directed to authenticate **before continuing** to use the app and submitting data and then potentially losing work (like submitting a form) which is not very user friendly.

You could potentially do this on a component by component basis rather than the main instance by using a Vue Mixin. This would work better for very short lived tokens that might expire while the app is being used. Put the check in the `mounted()` hook  of the mixin and then use that mixin in any component that makes api calls so that the check is run when that component is mounted. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use an interceptor with axios. Catch the 401s and clear the local storage when you do then redirect user to appropriate page.